# How to parse indefinite list of objects from JSON with Retrofit in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit2

I am receiving a JSON response in the following format:

```
"game" : {},
"datetime": {},
"status": {},
"teams": {},
"players" : {
      "ID8470607" : {
        "id" : 8470607,
        "fullName" : "Brent Seabrook",
        "link" : "/api/v1/people/8470607",
        "firstName" : "Brent",
        "lastName" : "Seabrook",
        "primaryNumber" : "7",
        "birthDate" : "1985-04-20",
        "currentAge" : 34,
        "birthCity" : "Richmond",
        "birthStateProvince" : "BC",
        "birthCountry" : "CAN",
        "nationality" : "CAN",
        "height" : "6' 3\"",
        "weight" : 220,
        "active" : true,
        "alternateCaptain" : true,
        "captain" : false,
        "rookie" : false,
        "shootsCatches" : "R",
        "rosterStatus" : "Y",
        "currentTeam" : {
          "id" : 16,
          "name" : "Chicago Blackhawks",
          "link" : "/api/v1/teams/16",
          "triCode" : "CHI"
        },
        "primaryPosition" : {
          "code" : "D",
          "name" : "Defenseman",
          "type" : "Defenseman",
          "abbreviation" : "D"
        }
      },
      "ID8473533" : {
        "id" : 8473533,
        "fullName" : "Jordan Staal",
        "link" : "/api/v1/people/8473533",
        "firstName" : "Jordan",
        "lastName" : "Staal",
        "primaryNumber" : "11",
        "birthDate" : "1988-09-10",
        "currentAge" : 31,
        "birthCity" : "Thunder Bay",
        "birthStateProvince" : "ON",
        "birthCountry" : "CAN",
        "nationality" : "CAN",
        "height" : "6' 4\"",
        "weight" : 220,
        "active" : true,
        "alternateCaptain" : false,
        "captain" : true,
        "rookie" : false,
        "shootsCatches" : "L",
        "rosterStatus" : "Y",
        "currentTeam" : {
          "id" : 12,
          "name" : "Carolina Hurricanes",
          "link" : "/api/v1/teams/12",
          "triCode" : "CAR"
        },
        "primaryPosition" : {
          "code" : "C",
          "name" : "Center",
          "type" : "Forward",
          "abbreviation" : "C"
        }
      },

      etc.
},
"venue": {}
```

The list of players for a given game is unknown (some games it's 40, sometimes 42, it changes).  How can I represent this data as a Kotlin class?  I tried representing it as an ArrayList, but when it's parsed I get the error `Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 111 column 18 path $.gameData.players`

I know that this means it was expecting an array (the one I defined), and instead got the JSON object ID8470607, but since the IDs will be different all the time, and the player list length will be different each time, I can't hard code in the fields like you would with another class.  So how should I represent it as a data class?

Here is what I currently have:

```
data class GameData (
    val game: GameInfo,
    val datetime: DateTime,
    val status: GameStatus,
    val teams: GameTeams,
    val players: ArrayList<Player>,
    val venue: GameVenue
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not receiving a list, `players` as defined in the example is a map. If you want to parse the example as it´s presented above  your GameData class needs to look like this:

```
data class GameData (
val game: GameInfo,
val datetime: DateTime,
val status: GameStatus,
val teams: GameTeams,
val players: Map<String,Player>,
val venue: GameVenue
)
```

this way you´ll have a map of players (for this particular example you´ll have to keys `ID8470607` and `ID8473533`)